# PHP - trying to insert data into database through for-loop but only one row is filled

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, insert, cycle

I am trying to insert data into database using for loop. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "objednavky";

// ******************************************************

include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('http://www.quickbistro.cz/cs/rozvoz');
$count = substr_count($html, '<li class="item">');
$jidloA = array();
$cenaA = array();

// ********************************************************

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    $message = "Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error;
} else {
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $count; $x++) {
        $cenaA[$x] = $html->find("span[class=price]", $x);
        $jidloA[$x] = $html->find("div[class=article]", $x);
        $jidloSQL = strip_tags($jidloA[$x]);
        $cenaSQL = strip_tags($cenaA[$x]);
        $id = $x + 1;
        $array = array(
            "id" => $id,
            "popis" => "$jidloSQL",
            "cena" => "$cenaSQL"
        );
        $sql = "INSERT INTO jidla";
        $sql.= " (`" . implode("`, `", array_keys($array)) . "`)";
        $sql.= " VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $array) . "') ";
    }
}

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Data inserted succesfully";
}
else {
    echo "error creating table" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

When I run the script it fills table my only with one row where only ID is filled with number 81 (number of items I am trying to extract). When I tried to insert just one row with without loop it was alright and row inserted item correctly so I am guessing the problem is somewhere in my for loop.

Comment: Not sure what are you expecting? You are generating $sql in foreach and calling query outside, which means only one record will be inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your `$conn->query($sql)` which runs the insert is not inside your `for` loop, so it is not being run on every loop, it's only being run **after** your `for` loop is finished and therefore it is only inserting the results of the final loop.

try doing it this way:

```
    for($x = 0; $x <= $count; $x++) {
            $cenaA[$x] = $html->find("span[class=price]", $x);
            $jidloA[$x] = $html->find("div[class=article]", $x);
            $jidloSQL = strip_tags($jidloA[$x]);
            $cenaSQL = strip_tags($cenaA[$x]);
            $id = $x +1;    
            $array = array(
               "id" => $id,
               "popis" => "$jidloSQL",
               "cena" => "$cenaSQL"
            );

            $sql  = "INSERT INTO jidla";             
            $sql .= " (`".implode("`, `", array_keys($array))."`)";
            $sql .= " VALUES ('".implode("', '", $array)."') ";

            if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "Data inserted succesfully";
            } else {
                echo "error creating record" . $conn->error;
            }  

        }
```